# how can i make count for a field in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, integer

**Flutter**

**dart**

**Firestore database**

I want to increment one number in a field in every time I send data to the same it's Id in firestore ,

i have done two ways but both of them are not perfect

first , with using `int variable` but in this case the variable will set the value to zero again when i leave the page or application , But I want to increase the field to one number every time I type over it forever

```
int count = 0 ;
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.documentUid).doc(currentUser.uid).set({                               
 "countM" : count++ ,                                          
  });
```

Second , I used the same field and added +1 to it. This method is very effective if the field already exists. But if it is not already exists, it will not increase, EVEN it will not be recognized

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.documentUid).doc(currentUser.uid).set).get().then((value){
     var get=  value.get("aboutMe");
   });

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.documentUid).doc(currentUser.uid).update({                               
     "countM" : get["countM"]+1 ,                                          
      });
```

**So friends, I want a way to increase the number by one every time I write over the field, whether it is for the first time or later,exists or not exists Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using FieldValue here is how

```
var _count = 1
//to add
 Firestore.instance.document('docRef').updateData({"numberOfDocs": FieldValue.increment(_count)});
//to subtract
 Firestore.instance.document('docRef').updateData({"numberOfDocs": FieldValue.increment(-_count)});
```

Comment: thanks for answer but still this set the value to zero again when i leave the page

Comment: what do you mean by leave page, if you want to show the count on page loaded get the data in initstate and show it.

Comment: it is count for messages for every single message